# Backbone JS view theory

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone JS, and am having some trouble wrapping my head around a concept.

I have an interface with panels, where one panel is displayed at a time on the screen. Each panel is controlled by its own view, with its own model attached. Now, each panel as an "activator" tab that can be clicked to show the next panel.

In *my* mind, those tabs are actually sub-views of the parent panel view. Without a panel, the tab shouldn't exist. However, all tabs must appear on the screen at once, so that the user can switch between panels (views). So essentially all panels (their templates, anyway) would be loaded, but hidden until triggered by the click of a tab, at which time its content will be populated or else updated.

My problem, architecturally, comes with binding events to the tab views. So, for example:

```
window.PanelTabView=Backbone.View.extend({

    className: 'view panel-tab-view',

    el: '#appPanelTabs',

    tagName: 'li',

    events: {
        'click a': 'test'
    },

    initialize: function() {

    },

    render: function(panel) {
        this.$el.append(this.template(panel.toJSON()));
    },

    test: function(x) {
        console.log(this.cid);
    }

});
```

So when the tab is clicked, every click event is fired for all tab views.

Maybe I should treat all tabs as a single view, then? But I like the idea of each tab having it's own view from the point of modularity in the template.

Or maybe I'm missing something greater about Backbone and its MVC-esque approach.

What would you do in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have a parent view that simply manages the tabs and then simply delegates the click to the tab views? It would be a pretty simple approach.

Alternatively, you could be using a router, and in the router you could create your individual tab views based on a particular route taken. This would allow your page to be linkable.

First Approach:

```
ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el : '#your-tabs',

    events : {
        'click #tab1' : 'tab1',
        'click #tab2' : 'tab2'
    },

    tab1 : function() {
        var t1 = new Tab1();
        t1.render();
    },

    tab2 : function() {
        var t2 = new Tab2();
        t2.render();
    }
});
```

With a Router:

```
MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes : {
        "tab/1" : 'tab1',
        "tab/2" : 'tab2'
    },

    tab1 : function() {
        var t1 = new Tab1();
        t1.render();
    },

    tab2 : function() {
        var t2 = new Tab2();
        t2.render();
    }

});
```

Backbone isn't particularly opinionated about how views are constructed, but these seems to fit into their line of thinking.

Treating all tabs as a single view wouldn't make much sense. It would be silly to re-render all tabs just because the data on one tab changed.

Comment: These are great suggestions. You make two good points. First, that there's no a "you must do it like this" when constructing views. Second, you're right that re-rendering all tabs makes no sense. I may or may not use one of the above, but I thank you for teaching me something.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand much of your problem but at least I got that you in fact have only 1 button. Therefore you shouldn't have several views (it makes no sense anyway).
What you could do however, is use a "selected" attribute in your models which your views would listen to. So basically, when the user clicks on your button, you'll get the next panel thanks to your collection (I guess), unselect the former panel (set the selected attribute to false), therefore its view would disappear, and select the next, and its view would appear. I'll put some code later if you need.

Comment: Actually I have multiple buttons (tabs). But when I click on a tab, the `click` event for all PanelTabView instances gets fired. I did find the problem, though. By omitting an `el` in the view declaration,  my events are fired as intended (one per click).